# Entity Framework DataContext returns empty values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, localdb

I have created a DataContext.

```
namespace Attendance.DataAccess.DAL
{
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
    using Attendance.DataAccess.Models;

    public class AttendanceContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
        public AttendanceContext()
            : base("AttendanceContext")
        { 

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

I have created a configuration.

```
namespace Attendance.DataAccess.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using Attendance.DataAccess.Models;
    using Attendance.DataAccess.DAL;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<AttendanceContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(AttendanceContext context)
        {
            context.Persons.AddOrUpdate(
              p => p.FirstName,
              new Person { FirstName = "Andrew Peters" },
              new Person { FirstName = "Brice Lambson" },
              new Person { FirstName = "Rowan Miller" }
            );

        }
    }
}
```

I have created an initial migration.

```
namespace Attendance.DataAccess.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class InitialCreate : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Person",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        FirstName = c.String(),
                        LastName = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropTable("dbo.Person");
        }
    }
}
```

I have created a simple api controller.

```
namespace Attendance.WebApi.Controllers
{

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Web.Http;
    using Attendance.DataAccess.Models;
    using Attendance.DataAccess.DAL;
    using System.Data.Entity;

    public class PersonController : ApiController
    {
        // http://localhost/Attendance.WebApi/api/person
        public IEnumerable<Person> GetAllPersons()
        {
            AttendanceContext db = new AttendanceContext();

            var persons = 
                    from person
                    in db.Persons
                    select person;

            // this is always an empty array
            // I.e. the web browser displays <ArrayOfPerson/>
            return persons.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

I have configured it as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="AttendanceContext" 
       connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=AttendanceLocal;Integrated Security=SSPI;" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I have also queried the database directly, using the Server Explorer and the Object Explorer. The database has rows in the Person table. Why aren't those rows showing up in the Entity Framework DataContext Person?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to run `Update-Database` in the Nuget Package Manager Console. The database that I was querying didn't have the seed values.